# Call to undefined function libraries_load()

Tags: commerce, theming

I am writing a custom module for commerce shipping and want to use the shipping company's web service code in my module.  My thinking is to include it as a library using the Libraries module. I use hook_libraries_info() to define the library but when I want to load it later on using the libraries_load() function I get the error message.  I'm using colorbox that is dependent on Libraries and that is working fine.  I have also made my module dependent on the Libraries module in mymodule.info.  What am I doing wrong?  Why is my custom module not able to use a function in the Libraries module?

Also, my module is an exact copy of commerce_shipping_example but it includes the hook mentioned above.  The code that I've tried:

```
libraries_load('commerce_shipping_mds', $variant);
libraries_load('commerce_shipping_mds');
```

and

```
if (module_exists('libraries')) {
  libraries_load('commerce_shipping_mds', $variant);
}
```

I've seen this question asked many times and almost all the answers has got something to do with the Libraries version.  I have tried all the available versions and still get the same error in apache2/error.log.

All of the code (except for libraries, off course) is in my commerce_shipping_mds.module file. The currently installed Libraries version is 7.x-2.2+5-dev and I see the schema version in the system table  for sites/all/modules/libraries/libraries.module is 7200.  I also see there is another entry in there sites/all/modules/libraries/tests/modules/libraries_test_module/libraries_test_module.module and the .info says :  This is an example info file of a library used for testing purposes.  Am I supposed to have an entry like this for my library?

Here is my hook_libraries_info():

```
function commerce_shipping_mds_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['commerce_shipping_mds'] = array(
    'name' => 'MDS library', 
    'vendor url' => 'http://collivery.co.za', 
    'download url' => 'http://collivery.co.za',
    'files' => array(
      'php' => array(
        'Cache.php',
        'Collivery.php'
      )
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Forgot to add - I'm trying the libraries_load() function later in the .module file.

Drush libraries-list gives the following output:

```
Name                   Status        Version  Variants          Dependencies
commerce_shipping_mds  Not detected  -        -                 -
colorbox               OK            1.5.14   minified, source  -
```

Comment: So which version of libraries are you using (also make sure you don't have multiple versions of the libraries module in your file system, in which case it might not be using the one you expect)? Where are you calling the function from? If it still throws that error with your second code example I would also guess wrong module version. You can also check your system table in the database for the schema number of the libraries module and the path to your module, so you can guarantee what version is being used.

Comment: Please post your `hook_libraries_info()`

Comment: The libraries test module is fine, you can ignore that.

Comment: Are you sure the Libraries module is enabled? Also does the server have necessary permissions to read libraries module files? What does `die(module_exists('libraries'));` output on the line where it's failing? If nothing then it means it's returning FALSE.

Comment: Libraries is definitely enabled as I use it with Colorbox successfully.  Permissions are 755 for www-data. die(module_exists('libraries')); returns 1

Comment: I've noticed now that the colorbox .module does not actually call the libraries_load() function but instead contains another function called _colorbox_doheader() that calls the libraries_load() funtion.  If I call _colorbox_doheader() or libraries_load() from within the .module file the same error is thrown. Maybe I don't understand how Libraries is supposed to work.  Going to try a different approach without a library and include the 3rd party API code in my custom module rather without using Libraries.

Comment: The `hook_libraries_info()` is missing the `version arguments` key.

Comment: According to http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.api.php/function/hook_libraries_info/7 the version is optional.  I tried adding a version by using the Colorbox code (and library) and calling that but I get the same error. I have now rather included the external code as two includes using namespace and my first functions are working.  Thanks everyone.